# Can I use a stored procedure as part of my calculation in a select statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, microsoft-dynamics

I have a stored procedure that uses a CTE to find total cost and cost per piece of an assembly (bill of materials).

My question is, is it possible to call the stored procedure as part of a select statement to calculate yield? I imagine it would look a little like this

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'BOM' THEN (SalePrice * QTYSOLD) 
- ((EXEC dbo.sp_GETBOMUNITCOST ASMNumber) * QTYSOLD) /* Dynamically select parameter for each line */
FROM
dbo.SalesLine
```

Comment: No, you cannot - but if you're not manipulating any tables, you could convert it to a **stored function** which can then be used in a `SELECT`

Comment: So a Table-valued function?

Comment: ... or a scalar function that takes n input parameters and returns a single value..... totally up to you

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a scalar function instead of a stored procedure to use it inline in a query.